# Making a weapon Game thing

Tags: java

and I need help on this project I'm doing in class. Heres what i've got!

```
public class Game {

public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int Naruto = 0;
        int DragonBallZ = 1;
        int Batman = 0;
        int Freedom = 0;
        int righthand = 1;
        int lefthand = 1;

        if (Naruto == 0) {
            if (lefthand == 0) {
                System.out.println("The command 0 has been used...");
                System.out.println("Processing...");
                System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println("You have been given the 'Kunai'");
            } else if (righthand == 1) {
                System.out.println("The command 1 has been used...");
                System.out.println("Processing...");
                System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println("You have been given the 'Shurikan'");
            }
            if (DragonBallZ == 1) {
                if (lefthand == 0) {
                    System.out.println("The command 2 has been used...");
                    System.out.println("Processing...");
                    System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                    System.out.println("Success!");
                    System.out.println("You have been given the 'Kaioken' Ability");
                } else if (righthand == 1) {
                    System.out.println("The command 3 has been used...");
                    System.out.println("Processing...");
                    System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                    System.out.println("Success!");
                    System.out.println("You have been given the 'Super Saiyan 4'     Ability");
                }
                if (Batman == 2) {
                    if (lefthand == 0) {
                        System.out.println("The command 4 has been used...");
                        System.out.println("Processing...");
                        System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                        System.out.println("Success!");
                        System.out.println(" You have been given the 'Batarang' ");
                    } else if (righthand == 1) {
                        System.out.println("The command 5 has been used...");
                        System.out.println("Processing...");
                        System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                        System.out.println("Success!");
                        System.out.println(" You have been given the 'Keen Eyes'     Ability");
                    }
                    if (Freedom == 3) {
                        if (lefthand == 0) {
                            System.out.println("The command 6 has been used...");
                            System.out.println("Processing...");
                            System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                            System.out.println("Success!");
                            System.out.println(" You have been given the 'Rope' ");
                        } else if (righthand == 1) {
                            System.out.println("The command 7 has been used...");
                            System.out.println("Processing...");
                            System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                            System.out.println("Success!");
                            System.out.println(" You have been given the 'Knife' ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So if anyone can help me, I'm trying to make 4 games, and each game has 2 weapons. When i run the program, I need the 1 weapon for that game. I keep getting the result of all games of that weapon number. So if anyone can help, that would be awesome! Thanks!

- Edit - 
  I'm also using Eclipse for the java program!

Comment: Your design is really bad. The code becomes long and awkward (as you can see). Also this question doesn't fulfill the requirements of stackcoverflow, so this will be closed probably (unless you edit it into the form of a proper question).

Comment: What does it **mean** if `DragonBallZ` is `1`? Is that a selection? What does it **mean** if `Batman` is `2`? What would be different if it where `1` or `-1`? Apart form the other problems (*massive code duplication being one), that seems to be a conceptual difficulty that you have. I can't even give you a hint as to how it *should* look like, because I don't understand what those variables should mean.

Comment: Im am sorry Kayaman if its long, but my teacher wants me to make it like an actual game if as it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your question is not that clear, I suppose that you expect your code to return

> The command 1 has been used...
>
> Processing...
>
> Accessing Game Server...
>
> Success!
>
> You have been given the 'Shurikan'

This doesn't happen because you're nesting your different kinds of game.

You should use the `else-if` statement when going from "Naruto" to "DragonballZ".

Here's the fixed code, hoping that I understood your question.

```
public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int Naruto = 0;
        int DragonBallZ = 1;
        int Batman = 0;
        int Freedom = 0;
        int righthand = 1;
        int lefthand = 1;

        if (Naruto == 0) {
            if (lefthand == 0) {
                System.out.println("The command 0 has been used...");
                System.out.println("Processing...");
                System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println("You have been given the 'Kunai'");
            } else if (righthand == 1) {
                System.out.println("The command 1 has been used...");
                System.out.println("Processing...");
                System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println("You have been given the 'Shurikan'");
            }
        } else if (DragonBallZ == 1) { //Changed if to else if
            if (lefthand == 0) {
                System.out.println("The command 2 has been used...");
                System.out.println("Processing...");
                System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println("You have been given the 'Kaioken' Ability");
            } else if (righthand == 1) {
                System.out.println("The command 3 has been used...");
                System.out.println("Processing...");
                System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println("You have been given the 'Super Saiyan 4'     Ability");
            }
        } else if (Batman == 2) { //Changed if to else if
            if (lefthand == 0) {
                System.out.println("The command 4 has been used...");
                System.out.println("Processing...");
                System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println(" You have been given the 'Batarang' ");
            } else if (righthand == 1) {
                System.out.println("The command 5 has been used...");
                System.out.println("Processing...");
                System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println(" You have been given the 'Keen Eyes'     Ability");
            }
        } else if (Freedom == 3) { //Changed if to else if
            if (lefthand == 0) {
                System.out.println("The command 6 has been used...");
                System.out.println("Processing...");
                System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println(" You have been given the 'Rope' ");
            } else if (righthand == 1) {
                System.out.println("The command 7 has been used...");
                System.out.println("Processing...");
                System.out.println("Accessing Game Server...");
                System.out.println("Success!");
                System.out.println(" You have been given the 'Knife' ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please keep in mind that, even if I'm answering, this is not the proper way to use this site!